# Invalid value specified for property 'groupTypes' of resource 'Group'

Tags: azure-ad-powershell-v2

I am new to Azure and I am trying to create a dynamic Azure Ad group through PowerShell by following below cmdlet:

```
New-AzureADMSGroup -DisplayName "GroupName" -Description "Des" -MailEnabled $False -MailNickname "Mail" -SecurityEnabled $True  -GroupTypes "Dynamic"
```

But I am getting the below error:

```
New-AzureADMSGroup : Error occurred while executing NewMSGroup
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: Invalid value specified for property 'groupTypes' of resource 'Group'.
InnerError:
  RequestId: 419e641b-a15a-4417-840c-ce30a3541d8d
  DateTimeStamp: Wed, 15 Jun 2022 05:25:33 GMT
HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureADMSGroup -DisplayName "Testgroup1" -Description "Group assi ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureADMSGroup], ApiException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.MSGraphBeta.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.MSGraphBeta.PowerShell.NewMSGroup
```

I am following this Microsoft Document:

[New-AzureADMSGroup (AzureAD) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadmsgroup?view=azureadps-2.0)

I tried to modify the command like below:

```
New-AzureADMSGroup -DisplayName "GroupName" -Description "Des" -MailEnabled $False -MailNickname "Mail" -SecurityEnabled $True  -GroupTypes "DynamicGroup"
```

But it did not work. I am still getting the same error.

How to create dynamic Azure Ad group? Did anyone face the same issue?

Comment: Replace **`GroupTypes`** value to "DynamicMembership" and check if it works.

Comment: Thanks but I am getting this error now: "A value is required for property 'membershiprule' "

Comment: Try this : New-AzureADMSGroup -DisplayName "GroupName" -Description "Des" -MailEnabled $False -MailNickname "Mail" -SecurityEnabled $True  -GroupTypes "DynamicMembership" -MembershipRule "(YourRule)" -MembershipRuleProcessingState "On"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and I am able to create dynamic group successfully like below:***

To create Dynamic group, make use of below PowerShell script:

```
New-AzureADMSGroup -DisplayName "RukminiGroup" -Description "Dynamic group" -MailEnabled $False -MailNickName "Ruk" -SecurityEnabled $True -GroupTypes "DynamicMembership" -MembershipRule "(user.department -contains ""IT"")" -MembershipRuleProcessingState "On"
```

By executing the above script, the Dynamic group created successfully like below:

[image]

[image]

**Reference**:

[Azure AD Group Membership PowerShell - Azure Lessons](https://azurelessons.com/azure-ad-group-membership-powershell/#Azure_AD_dynamic_groups_PowerShell) by Bijay Kumar.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please confirm if you have the AzureADPreview module installed?

-GroupTypes
Specifies that the group is a unified or dynamic group.

Notes:

This parameter currently cannot be used to create dynamic groups. To create a dynamic group in PowerShell, you must use the Azure AD Preview module.

The correct commandlet is as below.

```
New-AzureADMSGroup -DisplayName "Dynamic Group 01" -Description "Dynamic group created from PS" -MailEnabled $False -MailNickname "group" -SecurityEnabled $True -GroupTypes "DynamicMembership" -MembershipRule "(user.department -contains ""Marketing"")" -MembershipRuleProcessingState "On"
```

Comment: I already have AzureADPreview module installed. I confirmed it by checking Get-Module cmdlet.

Comment: The commandlet needs to be adjusted. Groutype  needs to have DynamicMembership as the value. And also needs to have MembershipRule.

I have edited the actual response with the right commandlet. Please give a try.