# Error setting group to dynamic with Change Group Membership Type

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to use the Microsoft function from '[Change group membership type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/groups-change-type#change-membership-type-for-a-group-powershell)' to set the group membership (to dynamic groups). However, I keep receiving the following error:

```
Set-AzureADMSGroup: Error occurred while executing SetMSGroup 
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: Invalid value specified for property 'groupTypes' of resource 'Group'.
InnerError:
  RequestId: 4a71f8fb-eab5-47eb-90c8-f3ff9e2fb657
  DateTimeStamp: Mon, 25 Jul 2022 03:53:14 GMT
HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
```

All of the code is:

```
#Script parameters go here
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$InputFile
)

#The moniker for dynamic groups as used in the GroupTypes property of a group object
$dynamicGroupTypeString = "DynamicMembership"

function ConvertDynamicGroupToStatic {
    Param([string]$groupId)

    #existing group types
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$groupTypes = (Get-AzureAdMsGroup -Id $groupId).GroupTypes

    if ($groupTypes -eq $null -or !$groupTypes.Contains($dynamicGroupTypeString)) {
        throw "This group is already a static group. Aborting conversion.";
    }


    #remove the type for dynamic groups, but keep the other type values
    $groupTypes.Remove($dynamicGroupTypeString)

    #modify the group properties to make it a static group: i) change GroupTypes to remove the dynamic type, ii) pause execution of the current rule
    Set-AzureAdMsGroup -Id $groupId -GroupTypes $groupTypes.ToArray() -MembershipRuleProcessingState "Paused"
}

function ConvertStaticGroupToDynamic {
    Param([string]$groupId, [string]$dynamicMembershipRule)

    #existing group types
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$groupTypes = (Get-AzureAdMsGroup -Id $groupId).GroupTypes

    if ($groupTypes -ne $null -and $groupTypes.Contains($dynamicGroupTypeString)) {
        throw "This group is already a dynamic group. Aborting conversion.";
    }
    #add the dynamic group type to existing types
    $groupTypes.Add($dynamicGroupTypeString)

    #modify the group properties to make it a static group: i) change GroupTypes to add the dynamic type, ii) start execution of the rule, iii) set the rule
    Set-AzureAdMsGroup -Id $groupId -GroupTypes $groupTypes.ToArray() -MembershipRuleProcessingState "On" -MembershipRule $dynamicMembershipRule
}

#foreach ($group in (Import-Csv -Path $InputFile)) {
#    ConvertDynamicGroupToStatic $group.Identity
#}

#Write-Output "Converted to Static"

foreach ($group in (Import-Csv -Path $InputFile)) {
    ConvertStaticGroupToDynamic $group.Identity $group.Rule
}

Write-Output "Completed"
```

I have a file input in line 3 which includes a *.csv with two columns:
| Identity | Rule |
| :--- | :--- |
| 282c0823-9afb-41f0-a851-48f826fd6c49 | (user.userPrincipalName -match "@.*Company.*\.au") and (user.extension_e9c5f70d1257416f85f210cef227dc2e_info -match "\b22\.\b(REA\.)[\w-]*7A") |

At the end, I have inserted code to call the two functions. I have commented out the function ConvertDynamicToStatic and am only using the function ConvertStaticToDynamic.

There is [another post that discusses the same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72656571/invalid-value-specified-for-property-grouptypes-of-resource-group). The situation is slightly different (as they modified the original code supplied by MS. Also, the answer is not helpful at all (at the article supplied doesn't provide any further assistance than the original MS post.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I am using PS7.

Comment: Note about question above:
I was trying to get the table to work, but couldn't. It displays properly in edit, but breaks when posted. I apologise, I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Please check this [**blog**](https://find-error.com/questions/62756307/create-teams-room-with-dynamicmembership-using-powershell-module) if it gives you a pointer.

Comment: @RukminiMr-MT, thank you for the assistance. I had a look at that, but it didn't solve the problem. It suggested using the command "Set-AzureAdMsGroup -ID $groupID -GroupTypes @("DynamicMembership", "Unified") -MembershipRuleProcessingState "On" -MembershipRule $Rule". I don't know what the "unified" part does, but I tried with and without that to no success.

Comment: I realised I did not mention which PowerShell version I was using - PS7 (I have added this to the question above). I realised this because I thought I would try running this through PS5 (because I know there are some differences). The result was a success. Does anyone have any ideas why that would be?

Comment: Are you able to run **`Connect-AzureAd`** on PS7?

Answer (score 0):

Please **note** that you need **`Azure AD Preview module`** to set group to dynamic with Change Group Membership Type as mentioned in [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadmsgroup?view=azureadps-2.0):

[image]

I am able to execute the script with **`PS7`** and **`Azure AD Preview module`** successfully like below:

[image]

[image]

To know how to install the **`Azure AD Preview module`**, please refer the below [**blog**](http://gabytes.co.uk/2018/10/08/how-to-install-azuread-preview-powershell-module/#:%7E:text=How%20To%20Install%20AzureAD%20Preview%20PowerShell%20Module%201,below.%20...%205%20About%20AzureAD%20PowerShell%20Module.%20) by gabytesadm.

*If the issue still persists, please raise [**Azure Support Ticket**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/).*

Comment: Thanks, @RukminiMr-MT. Do you use the -UseWindowsPowerShell command when importing AzureADPreview module (I get errors if I don't use it)? I tried the steps you suggested and I still get the same error.

Comment: Please use **`Install-module AzureADPreview`** command to install Azure AD Preview module.

Comment: After using Install-module... I then use Connect-AzureAD. When I do this, I get an error: " The term 'Connect-AzureAD' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet..."

Comment: Please try installing Azure AD module **Import-Module AzureAD**

Comment: As per my comments above, I have tried ```Install-module AzureADPreview```, ```Import-Module AzureADPreview -verbose``` and ```Import-Module AzureADPreview -verbose -UseWindowsPowerShell```. Regardless, when running the main script above, I get the error: ```Set-AzureADMSGroup: Error occurred while executing SetMSGroup 
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: Invalid value specified for property 'groupTypes' of resource 'Group'.```